# Change GRUB text size based on resolution

Tags: boot, grub2, display-resolution

So this is a very minor problem, but it would be nice to fix.

I have a laptop with a 4k screen and a monitor with a 1080p screen which the laptop is sometimes connected too (so GRUB appears on the monitor). On the 1080p screen GRUB text size looks fine, but on the laptop it is very small and you really can't see anything.

Is there anyway to actually make grub scale based on current screen resolution or just have a pseudo if statement, I'm really not too familiar with exactly how grub works any help would be nice.

TLDR: Make GRUB dynamically change text size based on screen resolution.

Comment: The link above directs you to an inappropriate solution, for you don't want max res, you want larger text in GRUB2. However, its second and unaccepted answer from Basharat Sialvi will solve your problem; it shows how to customize GRUB2 to enlarge the menu text. In the Appearance tab, you can lock in the sizing you need.

Comment: @K7AAY That's why they are duplicates is that they give you multiple solutions for questions.

Comment: Linked answer worked perfectly thanks for the help!